# How to consume Trino data with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, hasura, trino

We have a dataplatform built around Trino and Privacera and it is working well. It is possible to query data from dozens of sources through trino and authorization with Privacera works like a charm.

Then we have a new requirement stating that they want to consume data from Trino with GraphQL. We really don't want to write all the GraphQL schemas and resolvers by hand and were hoping to be able to use Hasura. But Hasura can only auto generate the schemas/resolvers for Postgres and a few others. Trino is not on the map.

We were thinking of mirroring the data that is exposable to the GraphQL users in a PostgresQL database, but that would defeat the purpose of Trino.

I am out of ideas and was hoping to hear if someone would expose the data to the consumers with GraphQL in some other way.

So, any ideas of how to expose the data queryable by Trino through some automatic tooling with GraphQL?